# UITableView HeaderView respect readable content guide

Tags: swift, uikit

I'm trying to make my table view fit into the readable content guides on iOS. I've been able to get my cells to follow the guide, but need the header view to do the same.

Right now when my table view is on an iPad header view spans the entire width of the screen, but I want the header to be constrained to the readable space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out constraints have to be to the margin of their superview to respect the readable content guides. Problem solved.

Comment: @thecoolwinter- can you provide a code example of the fix you used? I'm going crazy trying to get this working!